# UIScrollView problem on iPad with Multitasking gestures enabled (iOS 4.3)

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, multitasking, gestures

I've searched the web and can't find any answer.

I've got a simple UIScrollView with couple of UIImageViews. ScrollView is setup in IB with pagingEnabled = YES then in controller I'm setting up contentSize.

When I try to scroll on iPad with multitasking gestures enabled (with just a slight movement, when i swipe on half of screen everything is ok) ScrollView seems to scroll for couple of pages very fast and then returns to the page that it should scroll to. When I turn off multitasking gestures everything is fine. On iPhone everything is fine too.

Anybody got this issue and resolved it? Only thing I'm thinking of is to totally override scrollView gesture recognizers but there must be some simpler way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve done some more searching that multitasking gestures are enabled only on devices used for development so probably when they will be available to all this bug will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have been told by apple not to use screen covers as this will reduce the sensitivity of the capacitive screen.

The only solution I have found is to disengage "Multitasking Gestures" at least until Apple acknowledges this. You can verify this by trying other apps too like iBooks, Calendar, and App Store.

If your Screen doesn't scroll while you slowly slide your finger across the screen and yet you can flick your finger across the ScrollView to access the rest of the view, this may be an unintentional counteraction by the "Multitasking Gesture" functionality. I have also noticed while sliding my finger all the way across the screen the original view just bounces back and I cannot navigate easily.

This is also apparent in version 4.3.3 so it might be permanent :(